# Prevent multiple clicks with single item on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement my interstitial ad to the theme-changing icon, but there is a problem. When a user clicks on that icon rapidly, the ad will show up multiple times, which can annoy the user experience. Because no one wants multiple ads for 1 purpose. How to make it a single click, when the user clicks on that icon, it will go through the ad and the user can't press that icon again

**Code snippet:**

```
    var isDarkMode by remember { mutableStateOf(isSystemInDarkTheme) }

    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isDarkMode,
        onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
            isDarkMode = isChecked

            if (activity != null) {
                showInterstialAd(activity, context)
            }

            changeThemeViewModel.enableDarkTheme(isDarkMode)
        },
        modifier = Modifier.pulsateClick()
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.icon),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.lamp_icon),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(45.dp)   
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    var isDarkMode by remember { mutableStateOf(isSystemInDarkTheme) }
    var isButtonClickable by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    // Your click handling function
    fun onButtonClick() {
        if (isButtonClickable) {
            isButtonClickable = false

            showInterstitialAd(this, applicationContext)
            changeThemeViewModel.enableDarkTheme(isDarkMode)

            // Coroutine delay to make the button clickable again after a certain duration
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(700) // Adjust the duration as needed (e.g., 2000 milliseconds)
                isButtonClickable = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't implement these codes on IconToggleButton

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (Maybe try applying some delay to the line where it is enabled too)

```
    val isDarkMode by remember { mutableStateOf(isSystemInDarkTheme) }
    val isButtonEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isDarkMode,
        onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
            isButtonEnabled.value = false
            
            isDarkMode = isChecked

            if (activity != null) {
                showInterstialAd(activity, context)
            }

            changeThemeViewModel.enableDarkTheme(isDarkMode)

            isButtonEnabled.value = true
        },
        enabled = isButtonEnabled,
    ) {
        // content
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: have you tried it with the delay?

Comment: i can't write delay on that block, for delay, function should be suspend